# What are the differences in serial port RS232 vs USB programming?

Tags: serial-port, usb

What are the differences in serial port RS232 vs USB programming?

I have the option to interface with hardware in RS232 or USB and I'm not sure how to pick one.

What are the main differences if any when actually programming to the device?

Is this relevant to both?
Serial Communications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can depend on the hardware.

Some hardware, notably the FTDI chip family can do both, and it even provides libraries you can easily use for both cases. It even provides the functionality to emulate RS232 through USB.

The problem with limiting yourself to RS232 is that most modern PCs don't have physical ports for it. So it really depends on what area your application is used in.

Answer (score 2):

Programming a serial interface is WAY much easier. And there is also a lot of information on how to do it. I would choose RS232 without a doubt.

And .Net has direct support for them on the Framework. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).